# How could Lord Verminaard take Pax Tharkas?

Tags: dragonlance

In the conclusion of *The Dragons of Autumn Twilight*, the companions sneak into Pax Tharkas fortress occupied by the dragonarmies

> and release human prisoners held captive by Lord Verminaard, killing him in the process.

But how did the Dragon Highlord Verminaard manage to take the fortress in the first place? Flint claims that no army has ever taken it by assault, as the defence mechanism releases huge boulders blocking the gate, and it is impossible to lead an army around due to mountainous terrain. Was it treachery? Or was no one defending it at the time?

Maybe there is a companion book or prequel that answers the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't say for sure I think.  Pax Tharkas was evacuated after the [Dwarfgate War](http://www.dragonlancenexus.com/lexicon/index.php?title=Dwarfgate_War) when

> the army of Fistandantilus captured the fortress.

This was shortly after the Cataclysm (39 AC), and up until the events of the War of the Lance (348 AC), the history of the fortress suggests that it was [abandoned](http://dragonlancenexus.com/lexicon/index.php?title=Pax_Tharkas)

Therefore it is possible/likely that the fortress was unoccupied when Highlord Verminaard led the [Red Dragonflight into the area](http://www.dragonlancenexus.com/lexicon/index.php?title=Red_Dragonarmy) in 351 AC.

Comment: This is what we know from the main books (Chronicles+Legends). I wonder if there is a supplementary book, maybe a short story, that sheds some light on this issue (although they have a lesser level of canon)

Comment: I had always assumed that after Fistandantilus/Raistlin's forces took it, the dwarves never went back. Shortly after the explosion at Zhaman, the mountain dwarves closed their gates. There's no way they would have attempted to take back the fortress. Thus it was [abandoned](http://dragonlancenexus.com/lexicon/index.php?title=Pax_Tharkas) until Verminaard arrived.

Comment: @Alith, Your answer is confirmed by MyCodeSucks's link. Could you please edit it, so I can accept a verified answer.

Comment: @TimSparrow - edited now, is that ok for you to accept?

Comment: And thanks also to @MyCodeSucks for the comment